# Improve query perfomance of a union search view when querying just one table

Tags: sql, postgresql, full-text-search

I have implemented a simple full-text search on my postgresql database using a view. E.g. something like

```
  create view searches as 
  (
  select id as searchable_id, 'Person' as searchable_type,
         coalesce(last_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(organization_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(comments, '') as term
  from people
  union
  select id as searchable_id, 'Community' as searchable_type,
         name || ' ' || coalesce(comments, '') as term
  from communities
  union
  select id as searchable_id, 'Street' as searchable_type,
         name || ' ' || coalesce(comments, '') as term
  from streets
  )
```

This is a simplified example: it contains a union of 14 tables.

This way I can in general easily query all "records" matching a certain search-term. Nice. I can easily count them, and then I present to the user the nr of matches per "searchable_type".

The user then has the option to retrieve a specific kind, and then I bump into performance problems: querying the table always does a full-table scan, over all tables, even if I specify a specific "table" (searchable_type).

So to give an indication:

```
  select * from searches where searchable_type like '%something%' and searchable_type='Person'
```

takes about 5 seconds, and if I run the same query

```
  select * from (
    select id as searchable_id, 'Person' as searchable_type,
           coalesce(last_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(first_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(organization_name, '') || ' ' || coalesce(comments, '') as term
    from people) as searches 
  where term like '%something%'
```

returns in a ~40ms.

So how can I solve this? I would want to use the view but with the performance of the single query. In other words: how can I avoid the duplication of defining the query twice? (once in the view and once separately).

Ideas to improve the speed:

- use a materialized view with indexes, it should soar, but the data is of course dynamic so then we have the refreshes and not sure how costly that is
- use some kind of hints (does that exist?) so postgresql knows it only needs to check one table?
- instead of defining a single big view, define smaller views and the union the select per table-search-view so we have less duplication
- actually does it make sense to use a view in that case, why not build a query every time with all the per-table-queries ad hoc? Is there any performance benefit in using a view over a big query?

Comment: A tip: you can run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE your_query` and post the plan to https://explain.depesz.com for easier analysis of what is slow.

Answer (score 1):

If instead of using a string for "searchable_type", you would use an integer, you would improve a lot your performances.

You can add an additional table to get the corresponding integer id from String ("Person" for exemple).

Comment: One cannot create an index on a view, so not sure why you suggest this. I am also sceptical that using a number instead of string will greatly improve performance in this case, but I am willing to try that.

Comment: Yes! In the explain plan I can see the analyzer can now skip all the other queries, this is awesome, thanks.

Comment: I read this from the documentation (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html): 

CREATE INDEX constructs an index on the specified column(s) of the specified relation, which can be a table or a materialized view.

So I think this is possible (if you can confirm, it would be great). I think even if it is only on a single column, this might already be useful (because there it will enable advanced sorting (such as B-tree).

Comment: Well, as I mentioned in the question, one of the possible improvements I saw (but would rather avoid) is using a materialized view, since then I have to keep it in sync with the actual data. On a norma/regular view you cannot create an index, for obvious reasons imho.

Comment: Ok, so I learned from you too: I edit the line to remove the part about index in the answer.